# Starting a process on Windows from Go

Tags: go

Is it possible to start a windows process from Google Go? I´m looking for a Go package that contains something similar to C# System.Process type, or some alternative method of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go has also a [Process](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/#Process) type. You can use the [StartProcess](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/#StartProcess) function of the [os](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/) package to create a new one. Alternatively, you can also use the [Cmd](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) struct of the [os/exec](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package which is a bit easier to use.